# Replace values of a csv file

Tags: php, csv, command, line

I need to find and replace all the values of rows of a CSV using PHP;

I am trying this but its replacing even the headers to 0 and row values are not doubling as it suppose to.

```
public function checkForNumericValues()
    {
        // Read the columns and detect numeric values
        if (($this->handle = fopen($this->csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            
            $fhandle = fopen($this->csvFile,"r");
            $content = fread($fhandle,filesize($this->csvFile));

            while (($this->data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
            {
                $this->num = count($this->data);
                
                // Skipping the header
                if($this->row == 1)
                { 
                    $this->row++; 
                    continue; 
                }
                $this->row++;
                

                // Check and replace the numeric values
                for ($j=0; $j < $this->num; $j++) 
                {
                    if(is_numeric($this->data[$j]))
                    {
                        $content = str_replace($this->data[$j], $this->data[$j] * 2, $content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $content = str_replace($this->data[$j], 0, $content);
                    }
                }
                break;
                // print_r($content);
            }
            $fhandle = fopen($this->csvFile,"w");
            fwrite($fhandle,$content);
            fclose($this->handle);
        }
        echo "Numeric and String values been changed in rows of the CSV!";
    }
```

CSV is like this:
[image]

Comment: Why do you open the file twice?

Comment: What is the initial value of `$this-row`?

Comment: Why do you use class properties for things that should be temporary variables, like `$this->num` and `$this->handle`?

Comment: The `break` statement breaks after the first row of the file. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't update the entire `$contents` when you're processing each field in the CSV, just update that field. Your `str_replace()` will replace substrings elsewhere in the file; for instance, if the current field contains `5`, you'll replace all the 5's in the file with `10`, so `125` will become `1210`.

You can do it correctly by replacing the element in the `$this->data` array. After you do that, you can then join them back into a string with `implode()`. Then you can keep all the updated lines in a string, which you write back to the file at the end.

You can skip the header line by calling `fgets()` before the `while` loop.

```
public function checkForNumericValues()
{
    // Read the columns and detect numeric values
    if (($this->handle = fopen($this->csvFile, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        $output = "";
        $output .= fgets($this->csvFile); // Copy header line to output

        while (($this->data = fgetcsv($this->handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $this->num = count($this->data);
                
            // Check and replace the numeric values
            for ($j=0; $j < $this->num; $j++) 
            {
                if(is_numeric($this->data[$j]))
                {
                    $this->data[$j] *= 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->data[$j] = 0;
                }
            }
            $output .= implode(',', $this->data) . "\n";
        }
        fclose($this->handle);
        $fhandle = fopen($this->csvFile,"w");
        fwrite($fhandle,$output);
        fclose($fhandle);
    }
    echo "Numeric and String values been changed in rows of the CSV!";
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I am getting this error: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Comment: I have added this and its fixed  `$stdin = fopen($this->csvFile, 'r');
            $output .= fgets($stdin);` I am getting extra line added into the csv with all 0's.

Comment: Only need to figure why this extra lines of 0's coming from

Comment: Maybe there's a blank line at the end of the file?

Comment: ` // Skip the header
                if($this->row == 1){ $this->row++; continue; }
                $this->row++;`  added this part now it works